# Testcontainer cannot configure port binding

Tags: java, spring-boot, testcontainers, docker-java, testcontainers-junit5

I'm using testcontainer version `1.15.2`. Tests are run in intellij on windows 10.
I have a wiremock container. By default it listens on the port `8080`. I would like to map this port to let's say `8081`. So I do:

```
public WiremockContainer() {
    super("wiremock/wiremock:2.9.0-alpine");

    self()
            .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".*port:\\s*8080.*", 1)
                    .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(25L)))
            .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> cmd.getHostConfig()
                    .withPortBindings(new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(8081), new ExposedPort(8080)))
            )
            .withNetworkAliases("wiremock")
            .withExposedPorts(8081);
}
```

When the container is created it listens on the random port, not the `8081`[1]. What am I doing wrong ? What should I do to make the container listen on `8081` instead of the random port ?

[1]

1. I have another container that tries to connect on `http://wiremock:8081` and keep getting `Connection refused`
2. When I add: `.waitingFor((...)forPort(8081)(...)));` timeout occurs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot choose which actual port is used on the host machine. TestContainers chooses one automatically and makes it accessible through `getMappedPort(containerPort)` method on the container instance. You can also use `getFirstMappedPort()` if you only have one.

```
Integer hostPort = container.getMappedPort(8080);
Integer hostPort = container.getFirstMappedPort();
```

https://www.testcontainers.org/features/networking/

Answer (score 14):

You can use set port bindings

```
List<String> portBindings = new ArrayList<>();
portBindings.add("5673:5672"); // hostPort:containerPort
portBindings.add("15673:15672"); // hostPort:containerPort
container.setPortBindings(portBindings);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the alternative way to bind the port

```
container.withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> {
     cmd.getHostConfig().withPortBindings(
         new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(5673),
         new ExposedPort(5672)));
});
```